# Are there substances that behave as perfect conductors but not superconductors?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity, conductors, low-temperature-physics

Does there exist substances which below a certain temperature becomes as a perfect conductor but not a superconductor? A superconductor is both a perfect conductor as well as a perfect diamagnet. If so, what are a few examples of such substances?

Comment: Wikipedia says "no,"  that there is no known (or even theorized, so far as I can tell) physical material which is a perfect conductor without also being superconducting

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Can you share the Wikipedia link you are referring to?

Comment: sigh... it's really not that hard:  go to wikipedia and in the Search window, type "perfect conductor" .